# Average values in LinkedHashMap with dates as keySet by day of week

Tags: java, date, iterator, java-6

I have a `LinkedHashMap<Date, Double>` where the key are dates and a Double value associated to each entry. There is one entry per hour.

I need to average the values per day of week, so I get a list with the average value of all Monday entries of the first month, all Tuesday entries of the first month, all Wednesday entries of first month and so on. Then do the same thing with the following months. The output would be something like this:

```
KEY(Day of week per month)   |   VALUE(Avg of all values for the day of week on the month)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Month1Sunday                 |   23423
Month1Monday                 |   6452
Month1Tuesday                |   94402

...

Month2Sunday                 |   342755
Month2Monday                 |   10923
```

This is what I have gotten so far:

```
private void getDailyBase(Map<Date, Double> hourlyPrices){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int month = 0;
    boolean firstIteration = true;
    int counter = 0;
    Double acumValue =0D;
    Double result;
    Map<Integer, Double> averageAccumulator = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Double>();

    for (Map.Entry<Date, Double> entry : hourlyPrices.entrySet()){
        cal.setTime(entry.getKey());
        if (firstIteration){
            month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            firstIteration = false;
        }

        if (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month){
            acumValue += entry.getValue();
            counter++;
        }else {
            result = acumValue/counter;
            month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            averageAccumulator.put(month, result);
            counter = 0;
            acumValue = 0D;
        }
    }
}
```

I can accumulate the values of each month and average them. But when I try to figure out or construct the structure for the day of week basis, I just don't know how to do it or where to start. I've tried with different iteration structures, but I guess I´m not seeing the whole picture.

I'm using Java 6.

Comment: The classes `Date` and `Calendar` are poorly designed and long outdated. Even on Java 6 you may consider adding [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to your project. It’s the backport of java.time, the modern Java date adn time API, to Java 6 and 7. You will find java.time much nicer to work with.

Comment: We are supposed to migrate at least part of this code to java 11 later on, maybe during the next year. I´m keeping your advice in my notes in case we finally do that. For now I just have to stick to Date and Calendar as long as I can´t modify much in the project but just make things work modifying "as less as possible", and also because I don´t have time to do changes, test and deploy them. I know Calendar and Date are hugely obsolete, but I hope I can work with Java 11 (at least Java 8) soon... things are just easier there.

Answer (score 1):

## Using streams

You can do it pretty quickly with Java 8 streams, but this specific usage might get a bit complicated as a one liner, so you might want to split it a bit.

```
    Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
    Map<String, Double> weekInAYearToAverage =
            hourlyPrices
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    // Group all entries, where key is "MonthXDayName" and value is a list of entries
                    // This will give us Map<String, List<Entry<Date, Double>>>
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(dateDoubleEntry -> {
                        instance.setTime(dateDoubleEntry.getKey());
                        // Create String key as "MonthXDayName"
                        return "Month" + instance.get(Calendar.MONTH) +
                                DayOfWeek.of(instance.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
                                        .getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);
                    }))
                    // This would be a good place to split this line
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    // Map all groups, so we will have map where key is "MonthXDayName" and value is an average value or 0, if no values
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                            e -> e.getValue()
                                    .stream()
                                    .mapToDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)
                                    .average()
                                    .orElse(0)));
```

## Without streams

For Java 6 and 7, before streams were introduced to Java, use conventional looping.

```
    Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Group entries by "MonthXDayName"
    Map<String, List<Map.Entry<Date, Double>>> groupedEntries = new HashMap<String, List<Map.Entry<Date, Double>>>();
    for (Map.Entry<Date, Double> entry : hourlyPrices.entrySet()) {
        instance.setTime(entry.getKey());
        String key = "Month" + instance.get(Calendar.MONTH) +
                DayOfWeek.of(instance.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
                        .getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);
        if (!groupedEntries.containsKey(key)) {
            // If there will be a lot of entries, you might consider using LinkedList, as it's faster when adding big number of entries
            groupedEntries.put(key, new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Date, Double>>());
        }
        groupedEntries.get(key).add(entry);
    }
    // Calculate average for every group
    Map<String, Double> weekInAYearToAverage = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Map.Entry<Date, Double>>> entry : groupedEntries.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        double avg = 0;
        if (entry.getValue().size() > 0) {
            for (Map.Entry<Date, Double> hourlyEntry : entry.getValue()) {
                avg += hourlyEntry.getValue();
            }
            avg /= entry.getValue().size();
        }
        weekInAYearToAverage.put(key, avg);
    }
```

Comment: Damn, I forgot to mention, for the project I´m working on, I´m stuck with Java 6 (I´m maintaining old code that can´t be upgraded for now). I know streams would make things much easier, but I´m afraid I can´t use them...

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is working exactly as intended. I´m still studying this solution to fully understand how it works. I tried to do like this but I didn't know how to translate the schema into code, above all nesting maps and arrays in the proper way. I hope I can get this expertise level one day soon. I mean, not how it works or what is intended to do, but how to put it all together; it was just too much for my brain. Thank you.